# Configurable products problem

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product

I am trying to create 18 configurable products on our site.

I have created all the simple products (2688 of them), imported via csv. The simple products are common to all 18 configurable products.

I have created 7 products using Magento Admin area, and they are working correctly, and displaying correctly on the category page.

When I create product 8, and make status enabled, and assign to category, the category page becomes a blank white page.

This happens with all configurable products created after product 7.

I have

- cleared cache
- refreshed indexes
- deleted configurable product and recreated (same problem)

Any ideas on what this could be?

I am on Magento 1.8.1.0

Cheers
Danielle

Comment: What, if any, errors are logged in system.log and exception.log

Comment: system.log

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::resize(), called in /home/mysite/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/mobileshoppe/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 44 and defined  in /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php on line 177


>  ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: width  in /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php on line 179

Comment: please stop that's not going to be helpful

Comment: Have a look on here for "MySQL server has gone away"

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/429/217

Answer (score -1):

You likely need to install a lightbox plug-in you used before. I got the same error and that is how I fixed it.

Go to your Magento Connect and enter this key and install:
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/magento_easy_lightbox